# How to access a string from string.xml, while we are in a class other than main class?

Tags: android, getstring

To access a string in the main class the `getString()` method works very well. but what if we have created another class and need access to the strings?
I tried `Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.m1);` but this didn't work and caused the app to crash.
any suggestion?
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
String m1 = this.getResources().getString(R.string.m1);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that, I'll tell you mine.

Whenever I need to access some resource, I pass a `Context` as a parameter for the method.

Using a `context` variable, you can get resources like this:

```
context.getResources().getString(R.string.my_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the class is a Context, use `getResources()`. If it's not, then you need to pass it an instance of `Resources` from one of your own `Context`s. `Resources.getSystem()` returns a Resources object for the Android system, so it has Android's resources, not yours.

Answer (score 0):

`getString()` is a method of the `Context` class, so you need to pass the Context (e.g. the Activity object) to the other class. Than you can call `contextObj.getString()`.

See the [Context class documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int)) for more information.

A "quick and dirty" solution could be a static Context variable where you can assign the main Activity object at start time, but I don't suggest this way.